# Redirect gives me blank page

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, url, redirect, asp.net-core-mvc

im trying to make a shortner url mvc program and everything is fine, but the redirect method isnt working.

Truste me:

1. *database* is OK
2. string *final* is getting a value (http://www.youtube.com)

I dont know why im getting blank page as return

```
public IActionResult Redirection(string url_return)
        {
            string final = null;

            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Server=DESKTOP-28DDBR5\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=MakeItSmall;User Id=renan;Password=24025564;");
            conn.Open();

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT [BIG_URL] FROM [dbo].[URL_STORE] WHERE [SMALL_URL] = @URL_RETURN", conn);

            SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter();
            param.ParameterName = "@URL_RETURN";
            param.Value = url_return;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(param);

            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                final = (String.Format("{0}", reader[0]));
            }

            reader.Close();
            conn.Close();

            return Redirect(final);

        }
}
```

Route:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapGet("/{url_return}", (async context =>
                {
                    string url_return = (string)context.Request.RouteValues["url_return"];
                    RedirectionController rc = new RedirectionController();
                    rc.Redirection(url_return);

                }));
            });
```

Comment: You're calling `rc.Redirection(url_return)` but you're discarding the `IActionResult`. Why don't you just hit your controller directly?

Answer (score 0):

Do not use action for this, just add a class to your project root and then add a method that return the path you desire after that return the response as below

Try this code

```
    public static class Utils
    {
        public static string Redirection(string url_return)
        {
            string final = null;

            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Server=DESKTOP-28DDBR5\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=MakeItSmall;User Id=renan;Password=24025564;");
            conn.Open();

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT [BIG_URL] FROM [dbo].[URL_STORE] WHERE [SMALL_URL] = @URL_RETURN", conn);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@URL_RETURN", url_return);

            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                reader.Read();
                final = (String.Format("{0}", reader[0]));
            }
            else
            {
                return "URL of page not found";
            }

            reader.Close();
            conn.Close();

            return final;
        }
    }

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

            endpoints.MapGet("/{url_return}", async context =>
            {
                await Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    string url_return = (string)context.Request.RouteValues["url_return"];
                    string yourUrl = Utils.Redirection(url_return);
                    context.Response.Redirect(yourUrl);
                    //Tested//
                    //context.Response.Redirect("http://www.google.com");
                }).ConfigureAwait(true);
            });
        });
```